# How to stop postback in ajaxbeginform in asp.net mvc

Tags: postback

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Customer", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
{
 .................
}
}
```

How can ı disable postback in new ajaxoptions , what to write ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Json in order to prevent full postback in your page.
After that you must return to Partial View.

As instance;

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="UserName" name="UserName"/>
<input type="button" onclick="ButonClick()" value="Enter"/>
```

Javascript Code:

```
function ButonClick() {
var data= {
UserName: $('#UserName').val(),
};


$.ajax({
url: "/Home/MyActionResult",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json',
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyActionResult(string UserName)
{
var stringView = RenderRazorViewToString("_YourPartialView", model);
return Json(stringView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note:

You need below code to render your partial view for json.

Add below to your controller too.

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
ViewData.Model = model;
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
{
var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
}
```